# identify wrong value in a simple equation

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation

we are building an OCR system to handle atm receipts and it needs to read a lot of values ..but just like any system we need to build in some triangulation to ensure we dont feed wrong values into the downstream system. Also given the quality of images its bound to have misreads like 15/500 instead of 157500 or 15O145 instead of 150145 etc .. we do have a very simple equation that has 5 components (or maybe i can call them variables ..sorry not sure)

starting + increment - outflow - decrease = end

506      + 100       - 10      - 10       = 586

now if 506 was misread as 508 how can i be sure that its the first variable thats actually wrong ? this is a very simple and maybe not so clear example but i hope i got my point across..are there any interpolation techniques that can help me solve this ? deep gratitude to anyone that can point me in some direction

Comment: You cannot be certain of identifying which is the cause of an error: $508 +100-10-10=586$ is wrong but perhaps it should have been $508+100-10-10=588$ or $508+100-12-10=586$.  At least with *starting* and *end*, you might check against the previous *end* or next *starting* though the same misreading could happen with both.  If one entry is nonsense then it will be wrong, but others might be wrong too.

Comment: thanks Henry .. i thought so too and was wondering if there was something obvious i was missing ..i think we will simply flag such records for human evaluation :)